# why introduce a temp variable?

Tags: c#, events

I saw a lot of the following usage of event handler. Why they assign the handler to a local variable and then use the local variable?

```
event EventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    var temp = PropertyChanged;
    if (temp != null)
        temp(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    // why not just "if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(...)" 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The temporary variable ensures thread safety, because between the check and actual call other thread may unsubscribe from the event which will result in `NullReferenceException`.

Eric Lippert has [a great article on this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/29/events-and-races.aspx)

Comment: Can I ignore the pattern if I'm writing a winforms application which which only assigns the event handlers in the form loading events? The background workers are used to assign the data sources of controls though.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 mentioning background workers means that you already do some multithreading, so I'd suggest sticking with the temp variable.

Comment: I will use the pattern no matter what. Just curious of if it's safe if the background workers never unsubscribe the event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Because the PropertyChanged *could* change as a result of other thread's operations; in particular, it can be set to null just between the null check and the call.

Answer (score 0):

Because in a multi threaded environment if the last subscriber of the event unsubscribed after the `if` but before the invocation you will get a NullRefrenceExecption. By copying the delegate locally first it can no longer be modified by unsubscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine this:

```
if (PropertyChanged)
  PropertyChanged(...)
```

now just after the `if` the OS skips threads and the new one will remove the only subscription. After this `PropertyChanged` is `null` and you are in trouble.